# Como unir propiedades de objeto que están en un arreglo JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

**Necesito ayuda con los siguientes arreglos, espero puedan sugerirme una respuesta.**

Tengo dos arreglos y adentro objetos con diferentes propiedades, simulando 2 peticiones axios que me retornan data, como unir pasatiempo y agregarlo debajo de profesión en cada objeto. Espero puedan ayudarme

```
const obj = [
  {
    id:1,
    nombre: 'Isaac',
    edad: 25,
    profesion : 'Estudiante'
  },
  {
    id:2,
    nombre: 'Karla',
    edad: 22,
    profesion : 'Estudiante'
  }
];

const obj2 = [
  {
    id:1,
    profesion : 'Estudiante',
    pasatiempo: 'Video Juegos'
  },
  {
    id:2,
    profesion : 'Estudiante',
    pasatiempo: 'Estudiar'
  }
];
```

Como puedo hacer para tener un resultado como el siguiente:

```
const newObj = [
  {
    id:1,
    nombre: 'Isaac',
    edad: 25,
    profesion : 'Estudiante',
    pasatiempo: 'Video Juegos'
  },
  {
    id:2,
    nombre: 'Karla',
    edad: 22,
    profesion : 'Estudiante',
    pasatiempo: 'Estudiar'
  }
];
```

**Estaría agregando pasatiempo a cada posición dependiendo de cada ID y creando un nuevo arreglo**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si los dos arreglos tienen los elementos en el mismo orden, lo que puedes hacer es usar [`Array.prototype.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), lo que hace es iterar cada elemento del array.

```js
const obj = [
  {
    id:1,
    nombre: 'Isaac',
    edad: 25,
    profesion : 'Estudiante'
  },
  {
    id:2,
    nombre: 'Karla',
    edad: 22,
    profesion : 'Estudiante'
  }
];

const obj2 = [
  {
    id:1,
    profesion : 'Estudiante',
    pasatiempo: 'Video Juegos'
  },
  {
    id:2,
    profesion : 'Estudiante',
    pasatiempo: 'Estudiar'
  }
];

obj2.forEach((el, i) => Object.keys(el).forEach(entry => obj[i][entry] = el[entry]));
console.log(obj);
```

Iteramos cada elemento del array, obtenemos el índice y el elemento para ponerle los nuevos atributos al array principal, luego usamos `Object.keys` para obtener los índices del objeto, así los iteramos con [`Array.prototype.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) y vamos poniendo las nuevas propiedades al objeto principal.

Sin embargo, si los elementos están en desorden, vamos a tener que usar [`Array.prototype.indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) usando `map`, para iterar el array y comprobar si el elemento iterado tiene la misma id del elemento principal que estamos iterando, luego usamos `indexOf` para obtener el índice de `true`, y reemplazarlo en el array principal.

```js
const obj = [
  {
    id:2,
    nombre: 'Karla',
    edad: 22,
    profesion : 'Estudiante'
  },
  {
    id:1,
    nombre: 'Isaac',
    edad: 25,
    profesion : 'Estudiante'
  }
];

const obj2 = [
  {
    id:1,
    profesion : 'Estudiante',
    pasatiempo: 'Video Juegos'
  },
  {
    id:2,
    profesion : 'Estudiante',
    pasatiempo: 'Estudiar'
  }
];

obj2.forEach(el => Object.keys(el).forEach(entry => obj[obj.map(e => e.id === el.id).indexOf(true)][entry] = el[entry]))

/* Lo mismo extendido:
obj2.forEach(el => {
  const index = obj.map(e => e.id === el.id).indexOf(true); // Obtener el índice del elemento para reemplazarlo
  Object.keys(el).forEach(entry => {
    obj[index][entry] = el[entry];
  });
});
*/

console.log(obj);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda, PDT: Estoy tratando de practicar arreglos y objetos de JS te agradecería si pudieras sugerirme donde puedo ver ejercicios para practicar o tutoriales.